# How to fix FlowRouter.getParam from being 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I am adding a new page to a website, and I am copying the code that already exists and is currently working in the website. Why is the FlowRouter.getParam coming up undefined when it works everywhere else?

client/JobInvoice.js

```
import { Invoices } from '../../../imports/api/Invoice/Invoice';

Template.InvoicePage.onCreated(function(){
  const user = FlowRouter.getParam('_id'); 
  console.log(user);

  this.subscribe('invoices', user);
});
```

lib/router.js

```
Accounts.onLogout(function(){
    FlowRouter.go('home');
});

FlowRouter.notFound = {
    action: function() {
        FlowRouter.go('/404');
}
};
const loggedIn = FlowRouter.group({
    prefix: '/secure'
});

loggedIn.route( '/invoice', {
    name: 'invoice',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('FullWithHeader', {main: 
'InvoicePage'});
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

FlowRouter allows you to define routes with dynamic attributes ([path-to-regexp](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#routes-definition)), which are often representing document ids or other dynamic attributes.

For example

```
FlowRouter.route('/invoice/:docId', { ... })
```

would define a route that matches a pattern like `/invoice/9a23bf3uiui3big` and you usually use it to render templates for single documents.

Now if you want to access the document id as param `docId` inside the corresponding Template you would use `FlowRouter.getParam('docId')` and it would return for the above route `9a23bf3uiui3big`.

Since your route definitions lacks a dynamic property, there is no param to be received by `FlowRouter.getParam`.

A possible fix would be

```
loggedIn.route( '/invoice/:_id', {
    name: 'invoice',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('FullWithHeader', {main: 
'InvoicePage'});
    }
});
```

to access it the same way you do for the other templates.

**Readings**

https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergetparamparamname

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing and it works.

```
loggedIn.route( '/invoice/:id', {
name: 'invoice',
action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('FullWithHeader', {main: 'InvoicePage'});
}
});
```

Comment: so what the kind person above suggested then